# How to load html response in a page in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Can you modify this code

```
var url = window.top.SAMGLOBALS.base_url + menuItemUrl;
console.log("AJAX post URL: " + url);

jQ.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : url,
    cache : false,
    success : function(msg) {
            console.log(msg);
            //jQ("<div></div>").attr('id', 'dvShiftDialog').appendTo('body');
            jQ('#dvShiftDialog').load(jQ(msg));
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load the response you are getting from your ajax server page to the div with Id `dvShiftDialog`, you can use the `html` method to do so.

[html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method will replace the current inner html of that element with the new content (in this case the content of msg variable)

```
 var url="some-valid-url-to-handle-ajax";
 $.ajax({
           type : "POST",
           url : url,
           cache : false,
           success : function(msg) {
               $('#dvShiftDialog').html(msg);
            }
        });
```

**EDIT :** If you want to load the content of the whole page, why not have the container div load it with the `load` function , instead of making a POST call ? (i do not see you passing any parameter to the POST, so you can simply use the load method)

Assuming your HTML is like this

Now you can have this script to load some other content to it

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  var url="some-awesome-page-content-url.php";
  $("divContainer").load(url);
});
</script>
```

Make sure you have jQuery loaded to the page.

Comment: ('#dvShiftDialog').html(msg); is working but i just want to refresh and close it please modify that